# Accessing a UI component (Button) inside several other UI components (ExpandableListView - GridView) in Android

Tags: android, button, gridview, expandablelistview, layout-inflater

In a xml, I am having `LinearLayout`. 
Inside that I am using an `ExpandableListView`.
Every expand item contain just one view which is a `GridView`.
A `GridView cell` compose with three UI components which are `ImageView`, `TextView` and a `Button`.
How I have got control about those three UI components is as follow,

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) imageAdapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_grid_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.singleImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.singleGridItem_imageView);
        viewHolder.singleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.singleGridItem_textView);
        viewHolder.singleDownloadButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.singleGridItem_download_button);
    }
}

// ViewHolder is a static nested inner class
```

Things are working prety fine. That means each cell identify as different cells. 
They have different images, and appropriate `TextView` labels and also `Button` click event also working fine.
For the button click I have used a downloading with a `ProgressDialog`. That also working fine.
What I want is disable the `Button` when the downloading in progress.
Downloading happening in a seperate `AsyncTask` class.
Please tell me how can I disable the button which user has clicked for downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time I have to wrte the answer for my own question.
This one also the same.
I have figure out the way.
I have override the button click event in the `getView()` method as follow.

```
viewHolder.singleDownloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        // Some code goes here...

        new DownloadZipAsyncTask(imageAdapterContext, view).execute(zipFileUrl);

    }
});
```

By the time I click the Download button, I am passing the button **view** to the *DownloadZipAsyncTask* class.
In that class, I am again creating Button instance and set the view invisible as follow in `onProgressUpdate()`

```
Button mybutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.singleGridItem_download_button);
mybutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

For button, it is working. But I can't change the `ImageView` or the `TextView` like that.
Because in the click event, we only pass the Button view only.
Therefore I am again in a problem with how to update a progress bar like that.
Again, `ProgressDialog` is not a problem, only the `ProgressBar` UI component give the problem.

Answer (score 0):

set the click able property of the button to false in the on click method and enable it on post execute -- (view v)
then set the property of v

Comment: I have tried it. But it is not working. Anyway, thanks for the effort

Comment: Have tried that also setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE). Not working.

Comment: View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        
        holder.button.setvisibility(view.gone)}